# Perfect Randomizer

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, shuffle

I am trying to make an array, shuffle it, then go through it in order. However, when I shuffle it (START) more than once, it messes up! Also When you get to the last number in the randomized array, it messes up also! please help and thank you!

**JS**

```
var minnum = 1;
var maxnum = 104;

function start() {
  var nums = [];

  while(minnum < maxnum+1){
    nums.push(minnum++);
  }

  function shuffle(o) {
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
  }

  var randomnum = shuffle(nums);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = randomnum;
  localStorage["nums"] = JSON.stringify(randomnum);
  localStorage.setItem("current", 0);

}

function Link() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("current") === null || localStorage.getItem("nums") === null) {
    start();
  }

  var current = localStorage.getItem("current");
  var nums = JSON.parse(localStorage["nums"]);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = nums;
  document.getElementById('txt1').innerHTML = nums[current];
  current++;

  if(current > 103) {
    location.reload();
    start();
    current = 0;
  }
  localStorage.setItem("current", current);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="start()" value="Start" />
  <span id="txt"></span>
  <input type="button" onclick="Link()" value="Next" />
  <span id="txt1"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: "it messes up" how, exactly? What results or errors are you getting, what do you expect?

Comment: @Andy: Unluckily you went wrong while fixing: the function shuffle is **inside** the _start_ function! (I mean, in the original code it is) there is a _while_ right there messing up everything

Comment: I've made a fiddle if anyone is interested: http://jsfiddle.net/1pd18eun/

Comment: In any case, the error is probably that minnum and maxnum are declared OUTSIDE of the start function, so if you run that again it will not work, because minnum is already 103. http://jsfiddle.net/1pd18eun/1/

Comment: Gahhh. Are all the functions inside `start`? If so it's missing a closing `}`.

Comment: No @Andy, it is not, it is just bad indentation! if you want to take the code from the fiddle I've already fixed it, but there were no errors, just bad indentation and minnum and maxnum outside of the start function

Comment: Phew *wipes brow*. Thanks, @briosheje.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be that `minnum` AND `maxnum` are declared outside of the `start()` function and **never initialized to 1 and 104 anymore**, hence whenever you hit start the **second** time the first `while` will not push anything to **`nums`** array because `minnum` is 103 (from the previous cycle) and `maxnum` 104.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1pd18eun/1/

Code (just moved minnum and maxnum inside):

```
function start()
{
var minnum = 1;
var maxnum = 104;

var nums = [];
    while(minnum < maxnum+1){
        nums.push(minnum++);
    }
    var randomnum = shuffle(nums);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = randomnum;
    localStorage["nums"] = JSON.stringify(randomnum);
    localStorage.setItem("current", 0);
}

function shuffle(o) {
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
}

function Link()
{
    if (localStorage.getItem("current") === null || localStorage.getItem("nums") === null) {
        start();
    }
    var current = localStorage.getItem("current");
    var nums = JSON.parse(localStorage["nums"]);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = nums;
    document.getElementById('txt1').innerHTML = nums[current];
    current++;
    if(current > 103)
    {
        location.reload();
        start();
        current = 0;
    }
localStorage.setItem("current", current);
}
```

Besides, for the sake of readers and good people, start to indent your code, it was very hard to properly understand what you were doing.